# Install Monodevelop on a new Redhat 6.5 Workstation

Tags: installation, redhat-enterprise-linux, monodevelop

I've installed Mono and I would like to install Monodevelop. I tried to build the dependencies but with no prevail. My distro is rhel 6.5 Workstation. Can someone please show how this can be accomplished?

I've tried this but I get errors on gtk-sharp
[link-to-website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900575/install-mono-and-monodevelop-on-centos-5-x-6-x)

Comment: Isn't there a prebuilt package for this in [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) or Red Hat's [SC](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/1/html/Software_Collections_Guide)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed mono and MonoDevelop on a Fedora 20 x86_64 KDE and it's working. I've been using this for many months now, and never had one problem.

There is some problem with Monodevelop on Gnome.

I got the latest versions from [this](http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=home:tpokorra:mono&package=monodevelop-opt) repo, **the guy who built it said that you could try to use the Centos repo/packages for rhel 6.5 Workstaion.**

Excerpt:

For CentOS CentOS-7 run the following as root:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:tpokorra:mono/CentOS_CentOS-7/home:tpokorra:mono.repo
yum install monodevelop-opt
```

For CentOS CentOS-6 run the following as root:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:tpokorra:mono/CentOS_CentOS-6/home:tpokorra:mono.repo
yum install monodevelop-opt
```

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

**4.sept 2018:**

[He is still maintaining monodevelop-opt for debian and ubuntu](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=home:tpokorra:mono&package=monodevelop-opt)